# Issue with box around text

Tags: python

I know this has been asked time and time again; however, I couldn't find anyone else who managed to make it work using the code I'm using. There are several solutions to this problem - I am aware. But I want to know why **mine** doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something which is staring me in the face, but the issue I have now is that the box doesn't merge around the text; instead, it all just gets printed on one line. I've attached a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGsBF.jpg

Here is my code:

```
def Boxmaker():                                                     # Creating a function
    text = 'Arlidio'                                                # Defining Variable Text
    borders = text.splitlines()                                     # Spliting up 'Arlidio' into seperate lines
    boxwid = max(len(s) for s in borders)                           # Calculates length of longest word in 'borders'
    boxitems = ['|' + '¯' * boxwid + '|']                           # For the length of longest word creates box top border
    boxitems.append('|' + '_' * boxwid + '|')                       # Adds bottom border to existing variable 'boxitems'
    print(text.join(boxitems))                                      # Prints fused text
```

And the runtime result:

```
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|Arlidio|_______|
```

Comment: It makes sense to me that the whole thing is on one line, because your code doesn't use newlines at any point.

Comment: It gets easier, eventually :^)

Answer (score 2):

You've basically got three strings here, they are:

```
"|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|"  # top border
"Arlidio"    # text
"|_______|"  # bottom border
```

It sounds like what you WANT to do is to combine these in that order with newlines separating each one. That would be something like:

```
"\n".join([topborder, text, bottomborder])
```

Remember that `str.join` treats the object as the separator for the arguments, e.g. `",".join(["Hello", " World!"]) == "Hello, World!"`. Your code therefore is separating the top and bottom border by the text `"Arlidio"`, but doesn't put any newlines anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I basically got to this solution too. Though yours is very neatly put together. I'm sorry if you suffered an aneurysm because of me. Thanks tho, appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `new line`, or automatically everything will be printed on the same line, just to give you an Idea try this:

```
text = ' Arlidio'
borders = text.splitlines()
boxwid = max(len(s) for s in borders)
boxitems = ['|' + '¯' * boxwid + '|'+ '\n']
boxitems.append('\n|' + '_' * boxwid + '|')
print(text.join(boxitems)
```